# How to install webkit_server plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, webkit, capybara, capybara-webkit

I'm using capybara-webkit (1.11.1) to run following code with rspec:

```
    require 'spec_helper'

feature 'burnins', js: true do

  let(:user) { User.first }
  let(:project) { Project.visible_to(user).first }
  let(:folder) { create(:folder, project: project) }
  let(:clip) { create(:clip) }
  let(:playlist) { create(:playlist, folder: folder, clips: [clip]) }

  before do
    quick_login(user)
  end

  describe 'create' do

    after do
      attach_file 'burnin_file', 'spec/fixtures/burnin.png'
      expect do
        click_button(I18n.t('project.upload_burnin'))
        expect(page).to have_content(I18n.t('project.choose_burnin_background'))
      end.to change { Burnin.count }.by(1)
    end

    context 'in playlist' do
      it 'should create burnin and open edit popup' do
        visit playlist_path(id: playlist.id)
        click_link('btn_panel_burnin_ajax')
        click_link(I18n.t('project.create_new_burnin'))
      end
    end

  end

end
```

while executing this test this notification pops up:

[image: search plugin]

after a while it changes into:

[image: plugin not found]

is there a way to install a plugin with the need capabilities?

Comment: have you installed `qt` ? https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit

Comment: yes `qt 4.8` is installed